# Finding the Legendre transform of an "entropy type" functional

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, mathematical-physics, entropy

I want to find the Legendre Transform of 
$$T(f) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} f \log \left(\frac{f}g{}\right) \, dx$$
on a set $H_M = \{ f: f \ge 0 \text{ and } \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} f =M\}$, where g is some function in $H_M$.

i.e. finding $T^*(u) = \sup_{f\in H_M} (\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} uf\, dx -T(f))$.

The answer seems to be $T^*(u) = M \log (\frac{1}{M}\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} e^u g\, dx) - M\log M$. But I have trouble in getting that. Can anyone show me how to get this result? Thanks!!